# Asus Eee pc 1015BX memory upgrade 4GB

Tags: windows-7, memory, eee-pc

I upgraded the memory with a 4GB module. The bios recognizes it, memcheck sees no faults but when I press control alt. del. and go to task manager, it displays only 2048MB physical memory.
What is wrong? does it not support the 4GB module?  What can I do to make it use the full capacity?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 Starter is limited to 2GB. See [Physical Memory Limits: Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7). To use the full 4GB you need to upgrade to Home Premium.

Answer (score 2):

The [ASUS web page](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1015BX/#specifications) for this model shows the memory options of 1GB/2GB. There is no 4GB option, and [this article](http://laptoprelease.com/eee-pc-1015bx-release-date/) confirms that the netbook is limited to 2GB maximum. I do not believe it is possible to make this system use all 4GB that you have installed.
[Further research](http://www.netbooknews.com/40610/asus-eee-pc-1015bxs-2-gb-of-ram-permanently-soldered-to-motherboard/) shows that ASUS started soldering the 2GB modules into the machine so that they are not removable/replacable.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually using a 1015B with 4GB of ram. Windows 7 Starter has a 2GB limit and with an anytime upgrade you can get to Home Premium which will give you 3.5GB of available ram. If you use x64 version of Home Premium or anything higher you'll get 3.6GB available. So I suggest you check [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/videos/upgrade-to-another-edition-of-windows-7-by-using-windows-anytime-upgrade) link for Windows Anytime Upgrade.